# mock a c# dll function in pester?

Tags: mocking, pester

I am writing a test for a Powershell module that calls a c# dll function.
example : [Namespace]:: SomeMethod($param1, $param2)
Any ideas on how I can mock this method in my Pester test?

Answer (score 2):

Referring the Pester documentation mocking works only with powershell cmdlets, commands or functions.

In the the [description section](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Mocking-with-Pester#description) it says:

> Mock the behavior of ANY powershell command.

But you could mock it with a wrapper like this:

```
Function Invoke-FooBar() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mnadatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$param1,

        [Parameter(Mnadatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$param2
    )
    [Namespace]::SomeMethod($param1, $param2)
}
```

And then use the Pester mocking with something like this:

```
Describe "Unit1" {
    Context "Basic logic tests" {
        Mock Invoke-Foobar {return $True}
        It "Test1: Invoke-FooBar" {
            Invoke-FooBar | Should Be $True
        }
    }
}
```